# I am unable to make changes to the Rabbitmq configuration in Amazon MQ

Tags: amazon-web-services, rabbitmq, amazon-mq

I have Rabbit mq cluster deployed on Amazon via Amazon MQ. I am trying to add:
`log.exchange = true log.exchange.level = info`
to the configuration file and it throws the following error:

```
"Your configuration has been sanitized. Invalid and unsupported elements and attributes have been removed.Info
Element: log.exchange
Reason: Unsupported element.
Element: log.exchange.level
Reason: Unsupported element."
```

I have gone thru tons of AWS documentation and none of them seem to have clear instructions regarding the schemas and configs.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/latest/developer-guide/rabbitmq-broker-configuration-parameters.html

They do seem to have a better doc on Active mq schemas.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/latest/developer-guide/amazon-mq-broker-configuration-parameters.html

Comment: I suggest asking Amazon / AWS support for assistance.

Comment: AmazonMQ permits only a subset of configuration elements. Here's the list: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/latest/developer-guide/permitted-elements.html

Comment: AmazonMQ doesn't support changing `log` in the configuration at this time.